# Html5 canvas how to stop cursor changing onwheel

Tags: css, html, cursor, default

On my Html5 canvas and when I scroll up or down using the wheel while hovering over the canvas - the canvas zooms in or out, similarly to in google maps.

Unfortunately the browser automatically changes the cursor to a scrolling cursor, is there a way of stopping the default function?

Answer (score 0):

What OS and browser are you using? This seems like more of an issue with your system than with Canvas itself.

By default, Canvas doesn't react to scroll events, although you can make it do so. Are you using sample code from the web somewhere, or did you create your Canvas from scratch?

Comment: I have used it on Vista and windows 7, using the latest versions of chrome IE Opera and Firefox. I suppose the question is more how to stop the browser changing the cursor for any movement of the wheel. I created the canvas from scratch and am using onMouseWheel="wheel(event)" to call my function wheel which interperates the wheel and executes the function below: `function handle(delta) 
{if(delta>0){document.getElementById('canvasdiv').style.cursor='-webkit-zoom-in';.. code to make canvas zoom in .. document.getElementById('canvasdiv').style.cursor='auto';}
... more code to make it zoom out`

Comment: Oops, I misread your question - I thought that the scrolling behavior was the issue... haha sorry. I would try applying the css property `cursor: _type_` to your `canvas` element. If you want the regular arrow, then use `cursor: default`, or you can use `cursor: pointer` if you'd like it to feel a bit more "interactive". Let me know if that doesn't work!

Comment: Think the issue was using the touch pad on my laptop, don't think it is possible to stop the OS from changing the cursor. Thanks for your help anyway!